# How use a few columns using group by in PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How i can use COALESCE(price)? Because i got error "non aggregated", how i can use all columns in select with group by? COALESCE(price) - mean first value in group, but im need first and last value in group too, but how i can do it?

```
select MAX(price) as high, MIN(price) as low, COALESCE(price) as open, date_trunc('second', created_at) as secondVal
from "eur_usd_ticks"
where "created_at" > '2020-07-19 23:15:49' and "created_at" <= '2020-07-19 23:49:09'
group by secondVal order by "created_at" desc
```

Structure:
price|created_at

Comment: Please add you definition of `price as close`.

Comment: @Luuk, I trying to collect candles from ticks.
Example, i have 5 ticks on second, first tick - open, last tick - close, min and high.
My mistake: COALESCE(price) as open, but it not work...

Comment: please add table sample and desired output, it will help to understand the problem.

Comment: @ИгорьТыра, https://prnt.sc/tw9nmb, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`coalesce` is of no use. try this:

```
SELECT MAX(price) as high, MIN(price) as low, 
  (ARRAY_AGG(price ORDER BY created_at ASC))[1] AS open_price,
  (ARRAY_AGG(price ORDER BY created_at DESC))[1] as close_price, 
  date_trunc('second', created_at) as secondVal
from "eur_usd_ticks"
where "created_at" > '2020-07-19 23:15:49' and "created_at" <= '2020-07-19 23:49:09'
group by secondVal order by secondVal desc
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you. But order by "created_at" desc created_at non-agregated too, buy i can use secondVal. Thank you so much!

P.S. Possible to use created_at in order by? (for future)

Comment: Solved! (ARRAY_AGG(created_at ORDER BY created_at DESC))[1] as created_at_val. Thx!